# why in array single quotes not required according to the syntax

Tags: php

I have some little confusion. I want to access the array as follows.

```
$_POST['un'];
```

or

```
  $arr['empno'];
```

But when I try in double quotes, it gives out a compile time error I tried the following:

```
 echo "welcome $_POST['un']";
```

in un i saved username by query string which is out of this question i think.. .so i write welcome
i also tried

```
    echo "$array['emp']";
```

it also gives me an error. Whats the problem?

Comment: `echo "welcome " . $_POST['un'];` concatenate.

Comment: Add `{}` around the variable:  echo `"welcome {$_POST['un']}";`.

Comment: bro i know...but i want to use as i describe...sometimes i need this in my pages

Comment: @Jite by adding{}....what exactly happens

Comment: It's just how PHP is designed..

Comment: The brackets are needed when interpreting arrays. `echo "hi $name";` and `echo "hi {$name}";` Is basically the same, but the brackets are needed when calling a function/method (if i remember correctly) or an array.

Comment: Answers given below, so you may as well pick the answer that best answered your question, in order to close it. Otherwise, it's still open.

Answer (score 2):

When using double quotes in php strings you are telling php to interpret the string before printing it.
When using (associative) arrays or methods, you need to use the `{}` brackets around the value to make it work.

Simple variants, indexed arrays, etc. can be parsed by just using the double quotes, but when using associative arrays and methods, you will need the bracers.

More (and more in depth) info here: [Php docs (strings)](http://php.net/language.types.string)

```
echo "Some text... $array['key']";   // Bad
echo "Some text... {$array['key']}"; // Good
echo "Calling $var (simple) and {$var} (complex) is basically the same.";
```

If you want to do the 'cheapest' type, double quotes is not the way to go, rather go with concatenation and single quotes:

```
echo 'Some text... ' . $array['key'];
```

Comment: Even the [php docs in depth](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) don't explain at all, why `echo "$array['key']"` is bad.

Comment: Well, it's not "bad", it just doesn't work :P

Comment: Others are suggesting it does work, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70137669/3429430

Comment: No, in those cases they don't use any ' or " at all in the array accessor. Seems like that works as well.
Personally, I use { } around all variables, makes it cleaner and easier to read imho.

Answer (score 1):

Further adding to Fred's comment, if you would like to use array variable, you can use it like:

```
echo "welcome $_POST[un]";
```

This will output the value of array variable

Comment: Thanks for the mention, plus that's `not` my downvote, in case you may be wondering.

Comment: i also told...i already use it,,,,thats so i give title...read it agian title

Comment: You need to remove single quotes $_POST[un]

Comment: @Davinderkumar, you should have made that clear in the question, it is not clear in the title alone that you already know this syntax. I was actually going to post this answer before I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the references to the array with { and }

```
echo "welcome {$_POST['un']}";
```

and

```
echo "{$array['emp']}";
```