# Why does php need complex(curly) syntax to parse associative array values in a string

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

This question might be a duplicate of [why in array single quotes not required according to the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767555/why-in-array-single-quotes-not-required-according-to-the-syntax)

but I didn't the explanation I need over there. We know we can do `echo "$myArr[0]"`, but we can't do the same with associative arrays like `echo "myAssocArr['myKey']"`. I know we can use php complex syntax to get around, like `echo "{myAssocArr['myKey']}"`.

My question is, if php can access normal index arrays without complex syntax, then why can't it access accosiative arrays' values as well. What is happening inside php compiler/zend/whatever engine that prevents it from accessing assosiative arrays' values in a string without the complex syntax.

Comment: I can use `echo "$assocArray[mykey]";`.

Comment: @vee I did the same, but other posts on stackoverflow suggest it is a bad practice, because thats not standard php allowed syntax.

Comment: @vee None of your links use array keys without quotes. Here it says its a bad practise and might throw error https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622685/3429430

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. tested on PHP 7.0+. https://www.php.net/language.types.string Please take a look at **example 15** `echo "He drank some $juices[koolaid1] juice.".PHP_EOL;` It's without quotes (`'`). The answer from KIKO also no quotes.

Comment: But If this code `echo "$arr['mykey']";` <-- Yes, this will throw the errors. :)

Comment: @vee Here on [php official page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) it is considered bad practise, because if we have a predeined constant named `mykey` then `$assocArray[mykey]` will not take `mykey` as a key of the array, but a constant. I haven't checked may be it will throw error as well.

Comment: Please copy this code and test it yourself. ```define('mykey', 'My key');

echo mykey;
echo '<br>';


$arr = [
    'mykey' => 'key in array.',
];

echo "$arr[mykey]";```
It is different with constant. What I get from `echo "$arr[mykey]";` is **key in array.** NOT **My key** from constant.

Comment: It is completely different between `echo $arr[mykey];` and `echo "$arr[mykey]";`. The first one, if `mykey` constant is not defined it will be error undefined constant. But the second one will be no error if `$arr` array has `mykey` as the array key.

Comment: What error you have got? I tested on PHP 8.0.8 but no errors. This is the link to full formatted code. https://onecompiler.com/php/3xjpud64q

Comment: You are right. `echo "$arr[mykey]";` doesn't give error. Again, this is unexpected for me. Can you explain why?

Comment: I can't explain anything about this, please continue reading on KIKO's answer he's know better than I am.

Answer (score 1):

I read [the manual on variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

I don't think there's any reasonable explanation other than that `"` and `'` can be used to start and end a string. However, when you are parsing a string for variables you are already in a string. Those "tokens" are just not allowed in the *simple syntax*. Encountering a new begin or end of a string would make little sense. You can however use the syntax:

```
echo "myAssocArr[myKey]";
```

which avoids this problem. I agree it is not very satisfactory, but other than checking the PHP source code, I don't think you'll get a better answer.

Comment: _" and ' can be used to start and end a string._ ...  _Those "tokens" are just not allowed in the simple syntax._  They are, specifically single quote `'` is allowed. E.g. `echo "$var is a 'variable'"`. It is obvious for strings delimited with double quotes `"`, single quote `'` is not a start/end token.

Comment: @user31782 I was referring to the "simple syntax" used when parsing variables, not to what is allowed inside strings. See the link at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Yes in a _simple syntax_ single quote `'` **cannot** be a start/end token.

Comment: @user31782 I agree, but the algorithm used might not be aware of that. I made an assumption.

Comment: I still think it's not a good guess, because along the same lines, `echo "$var is a 'variable'"` should throw an error as well. This is my main question, what's so special about arrays that an otherwise allowed single quote `'` is no longer allowed.

Comment: @user31782 The PHP string parser is not in the same state, when parsing a string, then when it is parsing a variable. In the first state a single quote is allowed in a double quotes string, but when parsing for a variable, or array, after a `$` it doesn't allow a single quote. I'm not telling you anything new, this is actually what happens.

Comment: _but when parsing for a variable, or array, after a $ it doesn't allow a single quote_  But in `echo "$var is a 'variable'"` it allows for single quotes.

Comment: @user31782: You repeat the same point. In `echo "$var is a 'variable'"` the single quote is not part of a variable that needs to be parsed, but in echo `"$var['test'] is a variable"` it is. That is a different situation, which, as we know, is treated differently, and it has to because it is not a simple string, it is a variable inside a string.

Comment: Ok, it does make some sense now. I would still appreciate if someone could link to a canonical reference or actual compiler code to back this claim up. They are different as you say, but I don't see any problem for `'` to be a part of a variable name.